# FFMPEG problem with alpha the first image goes well in alpha but from the second nothing is displayed

Tags: ffmpeg

I made this script for 4 images the first image is in alpha but from the second nothing is displayed

here is the code for ffmpeg there is indeed an error but I do not. not understand it: [swscaler @ 0x7fef79845e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

```
ffmpeg -i vente_pp.mov -i 345_1.png -i 345_2.png -i 345_3.png -i 345_4.png  -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,scale=1080:885,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.01 [logo];[2:v]format=rgba,scale=1080:885,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.01 [logo2];[3:v]format=rgba,scale=1080:885 [logo3];[4:v]format=rgba,scale=1080:885 [logo4];[0:v][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,6)':format=auto,format=yuv420p [f0]; [f0][logo2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,6,8)':format=auto,format=yuv420p [f1]; [f1][logo3]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,8,10)':format=auto,format=yuv420p [f2]; [f2][logo4]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,10,12)' "[out] -map "[out]" -c:a copy 345.mov
```

here is the code for ffmpeg there is indeed an error but I do not. not understand it: [swscaler @ 0x7fef79845e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vente_pp.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-11-03T15:07:42.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:15.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25625 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (4444) (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p12le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1080, 25065 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-03T15:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : appl
      encoder         : Apple ProRes¬†4444
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-03T15:07:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #1, image2, from '345_1.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 101991 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from '345_2.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99367 kb/s
  Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, image2, from '345_3.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 104599 kb/s
  Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #4, image2, from '345_4.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 101509 kb/s
  Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '345.mov' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (prores) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> format
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> format
  Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> format
  Stream #4:0 (mjpeg) -> format
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7fde1f035e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7fde1e859c00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7fde220fe800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7fde1e93c000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] profile High, level 3.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] 264 - core 161 r3049 55d517b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to '345.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   15 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   36 fps= 33 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   56 fps= 35 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   77 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate=   0.4kbits/frame=   99 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  120 fps= 38 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.44 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  142 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.32 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  163 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  183 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.96 bitrate=   0.1kbits/frame=  204 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.80 bitrate=   0.0kbits/frame=  227 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.72 bitrate=   0.0kbits/frame=  24frame=  269 fps= 40 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.40 bitrate=   0.0kbits/frame=  375 fps= 40 q=-1.0 Lsize=     334kB time=00:00:14.88 bitrate= 183.9kbits/s speed=1.59x    
video:329kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.574562%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] frame I:2     Avg QP:12.45  size: 56370
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] frame P:101   Avg QP:14.91  size:  1949
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] frame B:272   Avg QP:16.23  size:    97
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] consecutive B-frames:  1.9%  3.7%  1.6% 92.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] mb I  I16..4: 24.4% 60.9% 14.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] mb P  I16..4:  1.2%  2.5%  0.6%  P16..4:  2.3%  0.3%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:92.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.1%  L0:45.3% L1:51.5% BI: 3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] 8x8 transform intra:58.9% inter:78.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 32.5% 34.7% 27.7% inter: 0.2% 0.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 68% 22%  2%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 13% 29%  3%  3%  2%  3%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 23% 11%  6%  5%  4%  6%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 72% 15% 11%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.0% UV:3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] ref P L0: 87.0%  1.0%  9.9%  1.8%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] ref B L0: 58.5% 40.3%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] ref B L1: 92.6%  7.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fde1e84e200] kb/s:179.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlay `vente_pp.mov` in front of the images. One method:

```
ffmpeg -i vente_pp.mov -loop 1 -t 6 -i 345_1.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i 345_2.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i 345_3.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i 345_4.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1080:885:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:885,pad=1080:1080:-1:-1[room1];[2:v]scale=1080:885:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:885,pad=1080:1080:-1:-1[room2];[3:v]scale=1080:885:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:885,pad=1080:1080:-1:-1[room3];[4:v]scale=1080:885:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:885,pad=1080:1080:-1:-1[room4];[room1][room2][room3][room4]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p" output.mov
```

Comment: Hello llogan how can I buy you a beer? to thank you for this code

Comment: @modN Thanks for the offer, but I had too many beers last night...